# How to open a file for both reading and writing?

Tags: python, file, file-io

Is there a way to open a file for both reading and writing?

As a workaround, I open the file for writing, close it, then open it again for reading. But is there a way to open a file for *both* reading and writing?

Comment: what problem you are solving? maybe there is a better solution than writing/reading a file, e.g. `mmap`

Comment: Could you give us your code so we will be able to answer you. You can also try to take a look: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files . However i have tried to use r+b and it works. Also is there any benefit to use one file descriptor in diff functions?

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk `mmap` is a great idea, but what if you have to deal with concurrency? Is there a way to reserve access?

Answer (score 445):

Here's how you read a file, and then write to it (overwriting any existing data), without closing and reopening:

```
with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(output)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: use `a+` to cover end-case that the file does not exist (will be created)

Comment: seek() and truncate() are both critical!

Comment: @JossefHarush Note that the documentation for `a` states 'on some Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position'. In this case the `f.seek(0)` won't work as expected. I just fell foul of this on Linux.

Comment: @Graeme - great input, haven't bumped into this behavior. what solved your case? `r+`?

Comment: @JossefHarush Plain `open()` isn't enough if it might not exist. You need to an `fd=os.open(..., os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)` to ensure creation, then `os.fdopen(fd, 'r+')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352231/2801913

Comment: It's better you explain why `seek` and `truncate` is used here. Most of the readers come from google and do copy-paste.

Comment: After you have read the file, the file pointer(fp) has moved forward, so you need to set it to the beginning. That's that `seek(0)` does: it places the fp to position `0` (*i.e.* the beginning). `truncate()` truncate the file to the provided number of bytes, *i.e.* removes all of the file content after the specified number of bytes. Imagine that your file has the string `Hello, world` and you write `Bye`. If you don't `truncate()` the content at the end will be `Byelo, world`, since you never deleted the text that existed in the file. `truncate()` truncates the file to the current fp.

Answer (score 354):

Summarize the I/O behaviors:

| Mode | r | r+ | w | w+ | a | a+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Read | + | + |  | + |  | + |
| Write |  | + | + | + | + | + |
| Create |  |  | + | + | + | + |
| Cover |  |  | + | + |  |  |
| Point in the beginning | + | + | + | + |  |  |
| Point in the end |  |  |  |  | + | + |

Decision tree for the table above:

[image]

Comment: What does "truncate" mean here?

Comment: @ConorJamesThomasWarfordHen in this context "truncate" means "truncate the file to a length of 0". I.e. remove all previous contents of the file and start with an empty file at the time of opening.

Comment: What does "cover" mean here?

Comment: @Flux You could use [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/)

Comment: `Cover` means `truncate`. For the meaning of truncate refer to the documentation for [`io.IOBase.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) and [`os.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=truncate#os.truncate).

Comment: How exactly does `w+` work? The docs say that it truncates the file upon opening, so does that mean that if you use `w+`, you can't read what was originally in the file? If python were to crash while a file was open with `w+`, might I end up with two files - the original as well as a partially written new file that was meant to replace the original?

Comment: taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function ?

Comment: This reply is one of thiose instance where picture is worth thousand words. Great diagram/flowchart.

Answer (score 53):

`r+` is the canonical mode for reading and writing at the same time. This is not different from using the `fopen()` system call since `file()` / `open()` is just a tiny wrapper around this operating system call.

Comment: it append file content, not write from beginning

Comment: fopen is a library call, not a system call.

Comment: `open` is a system call, `fopen` is not a system call. It's `fopen` that's a wrapper around `open`.

Answer (score 25):

I have tried something like this and it works as expected:

```
f = open("c:\\log.log", 'r+b')
f.write("\x5F\x9D\x3E")
f.read(100)
f.close()
```

Where:

> f.read(size) - To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which
>   reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string.

And:

> f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning
>   None.

Also if you open [Python tutorial about reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) you will find that:

> 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing.
>
> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'.

Comment: Also reading then writing works equally well using 'r+b' mode, but you have to use f.seek(0) between f.read() and f.write() to place the cursor back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Note that if the data you're writing isn't longer that the data already there, it will not get truncated. Use the `truncate` method to stop this.