# Why does os.fdopen() ignore "mode" argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This piece of code when run on Python 2.7.16 and 3.8.3 produces different results:

```py
import tempfile
import os

fd, lockfile = tempfile.mkstemp()
flags = os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT
mode = 'w+b'

fd = os.open(lockfile, flags)
fileobj = os.fdopen(fd, mode)

print(fileobj.mode)

os.remove(lockfile)
```

In 2.7 it prints `w+b` as expected but in 3.8 it prints `rb+`. Why wouldn't it be respecting the mode parameter in this way?

I've tried manually creating a file to discount `tempfile` differences but still get the same result.

I can't see anything obvious in the docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.fdopen
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.fdopen

Running on MacOS 10.14.6

Comment: `fd` already represents an open file; you can't change the mode. `fdopen` just gives you a Python object that wraps it.

Comment: From experimentation I think you can change the mode but you can only give it fewer privileges. E.g. if you open a file for reading in `os.open` you then can't change it to writable in the `os.fdopen` but the reverse works. Also, to answer my own question `rb+` looks to be equivalent to `wb+` (at least in this Python context) given the `+` opening the file for updates (read and write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the built-in `open` function:

> *mode* is an optional string that specifies the mode **in which the file is opened**.

When `open` is called with a file descriptor rather than a file path (or when you use the alias `fdopen` that requires a file descriptor), no file is opened. A Python file-like object that wraps the file descriptor is created and returned. You can't change the mode of an open file, so the `mode` argument is simply ignored.

Comment: I raised [Document that the built-in open() when called with a file descriptor ignores "mode" argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95498) CPython issue to add  this information to the documentation as it's clearly missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Python tracks this, but given your `flags` used in `os.open`, I'd say that `rb+` is actually correct.

You called `os.open` with flags "read/write" and "create if not exist", but without "truncate" (`O_TRUNC`). This is exactly the difference between modes `rb+` and `wb+`. Assume Python tracked your `flags`, it's the correct mode.