# Python Workers taking the same job

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a code that opens a bunch of files and works on them. It looks like this :

```
def process_work_1(file) : 
   with open(file, 'r') as f do : 
   ... 
   
   return 

def process_work_2(file) : 
   with open(file, 'r') as f do : 
   ... 
   
   return 

def main_execution(directory): 
   results = []
   workers = multiprocessing.Pool(None) 

   for file in os.listdir(directory): 
       results.append(workers.apply_async(func = process_work_1, args =(file)) 
   
   [result.wait() for result in results] 

   for file in os.listdir(directory): 
       results.append(workers.apply_async(func = process_work_2, args =(file)) 

   workers.close() 
   workers.join()
```

They go through the same folder and on the same file. But there is a wait for all between both runs and each file is only queued once.

Is there a reason why i sometimes get a permission error saying that two processus are trying to access the same file?

Comment: This looks odd. Even if all your threads would open the same file at once there should not be an issue. When you `open(file, 'r')` there should be no permission error problem,as you can easily open a file multiple times for reading [safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510634/is-it-safe-to-open-a-file-several-times-at-once-in-python) Do you have any `open(..., "w")` calls somewhere in the code we are not seeing? Or maybe some results from `listdir` cannot be opened as a file (are a directory or you don't ahve read permission)

Comment: Does the same code work when you write it as a for loop over the files instead of multiprocessing?

Comment: @FlyingTeller my mistake, i'm not explicit enough in my code. Each process opens a file containing data, and computes an output which is written to another file. so a process will receive a file "x.data" and outputs "x_modified1.data" and on the second function write "x_modified2.data". 

More explicitly it takes a structure and generates a matrix describing this structure with different methods and parameters. 

This is ran on 300 data file and puts out 100 variations for each of those data files. What is weird is that the crash will happen at random points and sometimes not at all

Comment: And you get the permission errors for the `open("x_modified1.data", "w")` calls?

Comment: Yeah exacly on that line