# Change all text in file to lowercase

Tags: python

```
from itertools import chain
from glob import glob

file = open('FortInventory.txt','w')

lines = [line.lower() for line in lines]
with open('FortInventory.txt', 'w') as out:
     out.writelines(sorted(lines))
```

I am trying to convert all text in a txt file to lowercase how would i go about doing this, here is the code i have so far and i looked at some questions on stack overflow but i couldnt quite figure it out, if anyone could link me to the right article or tell me what is wrong with my code i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: To start, you never iterate over the actual file. Should be "lines = [line.lower() for line in file]"

Comment: ahhhh duhhhhhh, dumb me thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Open the file with `'r'` for read.
2. Change `lines` to `file` in your list comprehension.

Here's the fixed code:

```
from itertools import chain
from glob import glob

file = open('FortInventory.txt', 'r')

lines = [line.lower() for line in file]
with open('FortInventory.txt', 'w') as out:
     out.writelines(sorted(lines))
```

Comment: it would make more sense to open the file `r+` and then seek to the beginning to overwrite everything and use an outermost `with open(...) as file:`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/open-file-for-both-reading-and-writing Explains what @oldrinb is saying

Comment: I agree. Maybe this is a question for meta, but I try to only change what's asked for or needed from original code so that it's easier to distinguish between what was just a styling change/optimization and what actually fixed problems. I'm glad these comments are here though to point to further code improvements :)

Comment: Awesome Thank you everyone! you all just saved me hours of work! I seriously LOVE YOU

Comment: @sizz why are you using `sorted` exactly?

Comment: @Enders thanks; the only points I'd make are that `truncate` is unnecessary here as we're overwriting the entire file anyway and of course we'd do something like `lines = [line.lower() for line in f]; f.seek(0); f.writelines(lines)`

Comment: @oldrinb was the only example i could find online lol for chaning a text file to lowercase what would the better option?

Comment: @sizz you can just use `writelines(lines)` without the `sorted` to keep the original line order

Comment: ahhhh o i see the sorted did happen to have a good touch to it !