# python 3 replace word in multiple files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a directory with a number of files in it.  I want to walk through the directory, oepn each file, replace a specific word with the same word but in Upper Case and then save the file.  I don’t want to change the file name, just save it with the changed word.

The script I wrote to do this is below.   The result is an error message

finf.write(FileinA)

io.UnsupportedOperation:not writable

Please advise what to do to get the desired result.

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk (sourcedir):
    for filename in fileList:   
        with open (filename,"r+", encoding="ascii", errors     ="surrogateescape") as fin:
        FileinA=(fin.read())
        FileinA = FileinA.replace('think','THINK')
        fin.seek(0)
        fin.write(FileinA)
        fin.truncate()
```

The error message is in the posting...fin.write(FileinA)

io.UnsupportedOperation:not writable
I edited the script to include "r+" and fin.seek(0) and fin.truncate(0)  the result is an error message Errno13 Permission denied ...which refers to the first file in the directory to be walked.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/open-file-for-both-reading-and-writing

Comment: *What* error message? Give a [mcve].

Comment: To **read and write** a file you should open it with `'r+'`  not `'r'`

Comment: The question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.  I had searched on stackoverflow before posting the question and did  not find a post that appeared to be a solution.  Please provide a link to the duplicate.

Comment: The error message is in the posting...io