# Why does JSONDecodeError correspond to the number of times this particular function is run?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In advance: I apologize for the vague question and long description. I cannot for the life of me pinpoint the problem and I am now desperate.

This is a small program meant to run on the command line. It allows the user to add or update an entry. The entries are key-value pairs of a dictionary--which is initially a text file on the same level as the script named `info.txt` which must be instantiated with "{}" (lousy program, I know. I'll work out kinks later). In summation, it reads a text file, turns it into a JSON object for manipulation, then writes back into the text file.

The script:

```
import os
import json
import sys


def addNew():

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
              "info.txt")) as entryFile:
        entryDict = json.load(entryFile)

    newEntry = sys.argv[1]
    newValue = sys.argv[2]
    confirmNew = input("Add \"{0}\" with \"{1}\" to the dictionary?"
                       "\ny or n\n".format(newEntry, newValue))

    if confirmNew == "y":
        entryDict[newEntry] = newValue
        print("You have added {} to your dictionary".format(newEntry))
    else:
        print("You have not added a new entry")

    entryString = json.dumps(entryDict)

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
              "info.txt"), "r+") as entryFile:
        entryFile.write(entryString)


def update():
    print("An entry with this name already exists.")

    entryFile = open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),                     
        "info.txt"), "r+")

    entryDict = json.load(entryFile)
    confirmUpdate = input("Update '{0}' with '{1}'?\n"
                          .format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
    if confirmUpdate == "y":
        entryDict.update({str(sys.argv[1]): sys.argv[2]})

    entryString = json.dumps(entryDict)
    entryFile.truncate(0)
    entryFile.write(entryString)
    entryFile.close()
    print("{} has been updated.".format(sys.argv[1]))


def main():

    entryFile = open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),         
    "info.txt"))
    entryDict = json.load(entryFile)
    entryFile.close()

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('usage: python3 {} entry value - entry manager '
              '\nentry: name of entry and its value to add to the dict.'
              .format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit()

    if len(sys.argv) == 3 and not sys.argv[1] in entryDict:
        addNew()
        sys.exit()

    if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] in entryDict:
        update()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works as intended, until I call the `update()` function twice. In other words, it brings up a JSONDecodeError only when I do `python3 file.py entryName valueHere` *twice*. Twice, because per the program, if an entryName already exists in the info.txt dictionary, then it is supposed to update that entry.
Why does `update()` work once, but not twice?
The error: `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` points to `entryDict = json.load(entryFile)` within the main function.
I've tried different variations of `load/loads`, `"r/w/a+"`. Nothing seems to work. What am I doing (mainly) wrong?

edit: any hints/tips towards general scripting/programming would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some extra characters are being appended to your file during write: `>>> open("info.txt").read()
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{"k": "v2"}'`

Comment: @thaavik where the heck did that come from? And how do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after you call `file.truncate(0)`, you don't write the new content to the start of the file. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate):

> truncate(size=None)
>
> Resize the stream to the given size in bytes (or the current position if size is not specified). **The current stream position isn’t
>   changed.** This resizing can extend or reduce the current file size. In
>   case of extension, the contents of the new file area depend on the
>   platform (on most systems, additional bytes are zero-filled). The new
>   file size is returned.

So after reading, truncating and writing to the file, the contents of your file will look somewhat like this (where `\x00` denotes a null byte):

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{"key": "value"}
```

To fix this, add `entryFile.seek(0)` after `entryFile.truncate(0)`.

Comment: Yep, this is the right approach.  See the first answer here for a cleaner way to open the file for reading and over-writing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/open-file-for-both-reading-and-writing