# Write function not working, read function does

Tags: python

When I use a write function in this code nothing happens, read works fine. Any reason why?

```
if userinp == ('save'):
    save = open("save.txt",'r')
    print(save.read())
    save = open("save.txt",'a')
    save.write("pop")
```

save.txt:
test

output:
test

desired output: 
pop

thank you for the downvotes :)

Comment: add `save.close()` ?

Comment: or Use `Context Managers`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open file for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/open-file-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: The file is likely buffered. `save.flush()` will make sure the contents is written to disk. `save.close()` will also flush the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: `with` is taking care of 'close` calls so that we don't have to:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the word 'test' in b.txt with 'pop', do the following:

```
if userinp == ('save'):
    save = open("b.txt",'r')
    print(save.read())
    save = open("b.txt",'w')
    save.write("pop")
    save.close()
```

The option of `'a'` in `save = open()` appends the word 'pop' to the file, the `'w'` option overwrites the content.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the content is in the buffer and not written to file yet.

You can add `save.close()` after writing so that the buffer is flushed out to the file.

Alternatively, you can do `save.flush()` to perform a manual flush without closing the file.