# Reading a list of tuples from a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a text file and I want to read a list of tuples so that I can add another tuple to it in my program and write that appended tuple back to the text file.

Example in the file
`[('john', 'abc')]`
Want to write back to the file as
`[('john', 'abc'), ('jack', 'def')]`

However, I whenever I keep writing back to the file, the appended tuple seems to add in double quotes along with square brackets.  I just want it to appear as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a reusable function which takes 2 parameters `file_path` (on which you want to write tuple), `tup` (which you want to append) and put your logic inside that. Later you can supply proper data to this function and it will do the job for you.

> **Note:** Don't forget to read the documentation as comments in code

#### `tuples.txt` (Before writing)

```
[('john', 'abc')]
```

#### `Code`

```
def add_tuple_to_file(file_path, tup):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as f:
        content = f.read().strip() # read content from file and remove whitespaces around
        tuples = eval(content)     # convert string format tuple to original tuple object (not possible using json.loads())
        tuples.append(tup)      # append new tuple `tup` to the old list

        f.seek(0)               # After reading file, file pointer reaches to end of file so place it again at beginning 
        f.truncate()            # truncate file (erase old content)
        f.write(str(tuples))    # write back the updated list

# Try
add_tuple_to_file("./tuples.txt", ('jack', 'def'))
```

#### `tuples.txt` (After writing back)

```
[('john', 'abc'), ('jack', 'def')]
```

#### `References`

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object/
- [How to open a file for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/how-to-open-a-file-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using json?

Comment: Sorry, there is no use of that here. I just removed that. I thought to do using that but left it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get the list object from the string.

```
import ast

s = "[('john', 'abc')]"
o = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(repr(o)==s)
o.append(('jack', 'def'))
newstr = repr(o)
print(newstr)
```

Here it is [in action](https://repl.it/repls/TemporalAmazingGeeklog).