# Random No Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

My concern is written below:

1. Why does this code return this error?

   ```
   import random
   with open('rn.txt', 'w') as f:
       for i in range(10):
           number = random.random()
           f.write(str(number) + '\n')
           content=f.read()
   print (content)
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-11-ddb88b6f5426> in <module>
         4         number = random.random()
         5         f.write(str(number) + '\n')
   ----> 6         content=f.read()
         7 print (content)

   UnsupportedOperation: not readable
   ```
2. Why does this code write only a single value to the file?

   ```
   import random
   for i in range(10):
       with open('rn.txt', 'w') as f:
           number = random.random()
           f.write(str(number) + '\n')
           content=f.read()
           print (content)
   ```

   This code is supposed to generate 10 random numbers and write them to the file `rn.txt`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your first code you try to read from a file you open for writing. In the second code you recreate the file during every run of the loop.

Comment: @Matthias, you mean reopen instead of recreate?

Comment: Your indentation is confusing. As it stands, that's not executable. But I'm also unsure about what you're trying to achieve. Anyway, this may help you to get started:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648493/how-to-open-a-file-for-both-reading-and-writing

Comment: @Sujay If one wants to write it like that the file should be opend in append-mode. But opening the file before the loop is a better idea. And of course reading the file makes no sense.

Comment: Both of these result in the same error. You cannot read from a file that you have explicitly opened only for writing.

Comment: Have a look at this image to better understand the different file opening modes https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/1362735

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to perform **both** read **and** write operations to a file which is opened in read **or** write mode. Choose one at a time.

For example, the following could work:

```
import random

# first open the file in Write mode ('w')
with open('rn.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        f.write(str(random.random()) + '\n')

# now open the file in Read mode ('r')
with open('rn.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```