# How do I append text to a file with python?

Tags: python, file, append

I am trying to make a file that I can continuously add '../' to. My code is as follows:

```py
with open("/tmp/newfile.txt", "a+") as myfile:
  myfile.write('../')
  contents = myfile.read()
  print(contents)
```

However, when I run this code it returns `<empty>`

Comment: Repeated question, you can find your answers here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706520/16020090

Comment: @UzzalH.Mohammad right my code should work according to all the tutorials I've seen but it doesn't.

Comment: To read and write together read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976014/16020090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Append File:**

```
with open("newfile.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write("I am adding in more lines\n")
    file.write("And more…")
```

**For Read File:**

```
with open('newfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
     print(lines)
```